# How to automatically get element height and use that height in overlay effect

Tags: html, css, height, overlay

I am not good with javascript or jquery, so maybe i will get help here. I need script, which automatically find element height, and put that height as css style in div.

I made simpe hover (overlay) effect, but as you can see in demo, when i am hovering image, overlay effect shows in all div. I need, that overlay will be displayed only in image dimensions.

I found this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.overlay').click (function () {
  alert($(this).height());
  });
});
```

But this script is not what i am searching for. It gives me height when i am clicking on the element. But how i can make it to show me automatically when page is loaded? How can i post height to div style?

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/450/550" class="image">
        <a class="overlay" href="#">
            <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
            <div class="description">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
                    consectetur adipisicing elit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
   <div class="information">
     <span>Some information, long text... etc</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

DEMO http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raVLgV

Sorry for my BAD english, and thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in first:**  make sure the jQuery has beed loaded in document, so add follow code in demo

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

**Second** the script

```
window.onload = function() {
$('.overlay').css('height', $('.image').height() );
}
```

why no using `$(document).ready()` ?

because `window.onload` will run after DOM and image load completed.

`$(document).ready()` run just DOM load completed.

Demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azOmom

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for bad english. It works.

Comment: @Tauras glad to helped you. if you have more images in one Document. you need use .each() and image.complete

Comment: One more thing. If i am have different height images, how can i set new heights to all images automatically? I am asking this, because i have maybe 50 images with different heights, and your script working only with first image.

Comment: @Tauras can you set the attribute height = '' for every image?

Comment: What do you mean? As i said, i am not friendly with javascript or jquery. I am using masonry, so image height is set to auto. Your script works only with the first image.